# How to run "exec" from the global scope in python

Tags: python

I have a Class. In that class I have a function.
In the function, I have a string variable that holds definitions of several python functions.

I would like **from the function** to create the functions that are defined in the variable, such that they will be created in the **global scope**.

After this operation, I would like to be able to call to the new function from the global scope.

For example:

```
class MyClass:
  def create_functions():
   functions_to_create = """
def glob1():
  return "G1"

def glob2():
  return "G2"
"""
   # ----> HERE IS THE MISSING PART, LIKE RUNNING exec in the global scope <----


# The following function should work:
def other_function_in_global_scope():
  print "glob1: %s, glob2: %s" % (glob1(), glob2())
```

What should be in the MISSING PART?

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Running exec is rarely recommended because usually there is a better way to design the code and it also introduces potentially very easy code injection. What are you trying to do with the string function names? Why do you have them as strings and not just objects?

Comment: @Zimm3r: I would like to give an internal customer an option to write some python code overrides I would like to use in my code.

Comment: That doesn't sound all that great letting them inject arbitrary code introduces security risks. Also there is better ways then using exec to even inject string source code. (Updated with a way to do it)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In python the overrides can monkey-patch anything anytime, but if you just evaluate a bit of code in global namespace, the risk of *inadvertent* symbol conflict. I'd suggest instead the customer would provide a module and your code would call functions in it if they were defined there (and default implementations otherwise).

That said, [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#exec) suggests:

```
exec(functions_to_create, globals())
```

Answer (score 2):

Several things first. What is your reason to creating a function to create other functions? What are you trying to do? There might be a better way. Also here is another way to so called create function that doesn't involve playing around with exec.

```
>>> def create_functions():
...     global glob1
...     def glob1():
...             return "G1"
... 
>>> glob1()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'glob1' is not defined
>>> create_functions()
>>> glob1()
'G1'
>>>
```

**Edit**

---

Injecting source code without exec (**THIS IS NOT A GOOD IDEA AT ALL**)

Have you customer submit their code then just do a custom import

1. Customer Submit Code
2. Save that code as say custom.py
3. In your code that you want to let the customer inject into do something like the following

   import os
   if os.path.exists("custom.py"):
       import custom
       custom.inject()

That way they can give you their code you call inject and they can change things.